16 GB memory limit capping on Linux with node.js
I'm encountering an issue where my Node.js process consistently crashes with a bad alloc() error once it hits around 16 GB of memory usage when working with strings, and around 40 GB when dealing with numbers.
What's puzzling is that my system has over 150 GB of free memory available, so I don't understand why Node.js is unable to allocate more memory. I've tried increasing the --max-old-space-size flag to 100 GB, but the problem persists.
Has anyone experienced this issue before, or does anyone have any deeper insights into why Node.js/ V8-heap might be hitting this memory limit despite having ample resources available? Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!
Here’s what I’ve observed and tested:
Experiment 1: Detecting Memory Fragmentation
I started by attempting to create a single large object, which consistently failed once it exceeded 16GB. However, when creating a structure composed of multiple nested objects, I was able to surpass this limit. This behavior led me to suspect that the memory might be fragmented, preventing the allocation of a contiguous block larger than 16GB.
Experiment 2: Chunked Array with Numbers
To further investigate, I implemented a chunked array structure to mitigate potential memory fragmentation:
code:
class ChunkedArray {
    constructor(chunkSize = 100000) {
        this.chunkSize = chunkSize;
        this.chunks = [];
    }

    _getChunkAndIndex(index) {
        const chunkIndex = Math.floor(index / this.chunkSize);
        const indexInChunk = index % this.chunkSize;
        return { chunkIndex, indexInChunk };
    }

    set(index, value) {
        const { chunkIndex, indexInChunk } = this._getChunkAndIndex(index);
        if (!this.chunks[chunkIndex]) {
            this.chunks[chunkIndex] = new Array(this.chunkSize);
        }
        this.chunks[chunkIndex][indexInChunk] = value;
    }

    get(index) {
        const { chunkIndex, indexInChunk } = this._getChunkAndIndex(index);
        const chunk = this.chunks[chunkIndex];
        return chunk ? chunk[indexInChunk] : undefined;
    }

    get length() {
        return this.chunks.length * this.chunkSize;
    }
}

let largeArray = new ChunkedArray();

for (let i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    largeArray.set(i, i * 2);
}

Using this approach, I was able to push memory usage up to 40GB without any issues when dealing with numbers.
Experiment 3: Chunked Array with Strings
When I modified the above experiment to store 1KB strings instead of numbers:
code:
largeArray.set(i, 'a'.repeat(1024));

The process consistently crashed at the 16GB mark after inserting around 60 million values.
Conclusion
This leads me to believe there’s something specific about Node.js or V8's memory management that causes these bad alloc() errors with strings, despite having sufficient memory available and enough memory allocated using --max-old-space-size flag. The discrepancy between how numbers and strings are handled further suggests this might be related to memory fragmentation or internal V8 limitations.
Has anyone encountered similar issues or can provide insights into Node.js/V8 memory management that might explain this behavior?

which node version are you using ?

While I can't reproduce your experiment 3 (using Node 22, the test runs to completion without error), I can confirm that in addition to the overall heap limit there are various per-object limits. Each individual object, array, string, Map, Set, BigInt, etc has a size limit that's well below (and unaffected by) the overall heap limit. See, for example, this related question about Maps.
If you have a case that actually runs into one of these limits, then splitting your data is often your best option. The ChunkedArray in your question is one example of doing that. (If you want to deploy that in production, you could make it more efficient by using a power of two as the chunk size, so you can use bitwise shifting and masking instead of floating-point division and modulo -- assuming that 32-bit indices are enough for your use case.)
Or, perhaps, you can get by with simply less data, or a streaming approach. Obviously it depends on the use case whether such techniques are applicable.

Hey thankyou for answering,
In experiment 3, did you try the complete experiment 2 code by with only the change mentioned in experiment 3.
for ex-
run the entire experiment 2 but instead of doing largeArray.set(i, i * 2), do largeArray.set(i, 'a'.repeat(1024)) 1 billion times and see if you're able to complete it without any error.

Also despite having over 100 GB of available RAM, my Node.js process crashes consistently when memory usage approaches 16 GB. This issue persists even when using multiple data structures (e.g., arrays) combined.
So even if I create multiple arrays, within their specific limits then also they crash when the overall memory reaches 16 GB even when I have increased the heap memory to 400 Gb using max-old-space-size flag.
It seems like a memory management issue specific to Node.js or V8. Any insights or suggestions for overcoming this limitation would be greatly appreciated.

@KumarAditya Yes, I've run experiment 3 by replacing one line of experiment 2's big loop. -- Suggestion: update your Node version, or at least tell us what version you've been using so far.

Hey @jmrk thankyou,
I have been using v16.20.2 and I was not able to exceed the hard limit of 16 GB in memory storage in node.JS which is equivalent to about 67 million 1kb keys insertion in an array.
Can you give me an insight of about how many 1 kb keys were you able to insert in the array without any failure in version 22.
It would be really helpful.

@KumarAditya Obviously that depends on the heap size. With a max old space size of 20000 MB, about 80.6 million elements. With an old space size of 40000 MB, about 161.2 million elements, so no surprise there: twice the heap size, twice the elements. Note that 'a'.repeat(1024) does not create a string that's 1KB in size (it's much smaller thanks to using "cons strings" under the hood), but such is the nature of microbenchmarks: they never do what you think they're doing :)

that's what my problem is. In the above version i set the max old space flag to 400 GB and i also have that memory to be utilized but still the node process crashes every time at 16GB (about 67million insertions in the array). I was never able to cross this 16 GB memory limit in linux (with the above version at least). Is there some upgrade in node versions (and in which one) after version 16 regarding this memory issue?? Any insight on this would be great.

@KumarAditya I don't know, but there is a little tool called "Node Version Manager" (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) that makes it very easy for you to test a bunch of Node versions and find out.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
